# NOT operation to NSString with Hexadecimal value Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, binary, decimal, hex

I am getting the value of a UISlider like this:

```
int value = (int)sender.value;
```

This values is between 0-100. Now what it needs to do is get the Hexadecimal value of this integer and also get the NOT value. So i get the hexadecimal like this:

```
NSString *hexedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%X", value];
```

if the decimal integer is 100 the hexadecimal is 64 wich is 01100100 in binary, the NOT operation of the binary should be 10011011 in hexadecimal is 9B. How can i achieve this NOT operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `~` operator to toggle all of the bits.

```
int value = sender.value;
value = ~value; // toggle bits
value &= 0xff; // force to 8-bits - optional
```